# numpy.tile for 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have to get 3D array demension (4, 2, 1) from two value (60, 80)

```
import numpy as np
array([[[ 60.],
        [ 60.]],
   [[ 60.],
    [ 60.]],
   [[ 80.],
    [ 80.]],
   [[ 80.],
    [ 80.]]])
```

I do as below

```
a = np.array([[[ 60.]],
       [[ 80.]]])
np.tile(a, (2, 2,1))
```

and get

```
array([[[ 60.],
        [ 60.]],
       [[ 80.],
        [ 80.]],
       [[ 60.],
        [ 60.]],
       [[ 80.],
        [ 80.]]])
```

How to get the expected array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use combined `np.tile` with `np.repeat`:

```
a = np.array([[[ 60.]],
       [[ 80.]]])
np.repeat(np.tile(a, (1,2,1)), 2, axis=0)

#array([[[ 60.],
#        [ 60.]],

#       [[ 60.],
#        [ 60.]],

#       [[ 80.],
#        [ 80.]],

#       [[ 80.],
#        [ 80.]]])
```

Or use `np.repeat` + `reshape`:

```
np.repeat(a, 4).reshape(4,2,1)
#array([[[ 60.],
#        [ 60.]],

#       [[ 60.],
#        [ 60.]],

#       [[ 80.],
#        [ 80.]],

#       [[ 80.],
#        [ 80.]]])
```